# which is better Redis inhouse setup vs Redis cloud setup for productions and development environments?

Tags: caching, redis, in-memory-database, redis-cluster, redis-server

Based on the parameters

1. Cost
2. Hardware Requirements (RAM,Nodes etc)

Also elaborate availability requirements for production and development environments.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your development / production setup environment. For both development and production- its better to go with Cloud setup.

Because - assuming you need to serve reasonable load in production, you would need less or more instances ( cloud instance such as redis on docker ) so that you can get the benefit of cloud auto-scaling.
For pre-prod and prod - you would need more load - may be two (min - for disaster recovery or blue green deployment) to more instances. For dev just one instance should be sufficient.